# VBA - Check whether a parameter is set using the bit key

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

i have a dialog with a few parameters (arround 20).
Every parameter gets a value like 1,2,4,8,16,32 and so on.
By closing dialog an integer will be set with the sum of the parameter like 2+8+16+64.

Now i have a few options to run my program. 
For example:

The first option needs to run the parameter 2,8 and 16 so i need to check if 2,8 and 16 will be checked in my integer.

I know that there is a way but not really how.
Maybe u can help.
Thanks
Jassin

The first option need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the [And operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zy95hw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) on a mask (m, interesting bits set) and your data (d, e). If the result is equal to m, then all the bits set in m are set in the data.

```
>> d = 4 + 2 + 1
>> e = 4 + 1
>> m = 4 + 2 + 1
>> WScript.Echo 0, CStr(m = (d And m))
>> WScript.Echo 1, CStr(m = (e And m))
>>
0 True
1 False
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed!